# Can't observe UIPageControl's currentPage changes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, uipagecontrol

I've a subclass of UIPageControl, and I'd like to observe the changes in [`currentPage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/1621234-currentpage).

Unfortunately, my `currentPage`'s `didSet` isn't called when currentPage changes from taps on MyPageControl.

```
class MyPageControl: UIPageControl {
    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            // not called when `currentPage` is changed from a tap
            updateSomething(for: currentPage)
        }
    }
}
```

And the change can't be observed using KVO either:

```
class MyPageControl: UIPageControl {
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        observation = observe(\.currentPage) { (_, _) in
            // not called when `currentPage` is changed from a tap
            updateSomething(for: self.currentPage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your didSet getting called when programmatically setting currentPage?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh yes. The reason why it doesn't work when changed from a tap is that the implementation of UIPageControl is possibly written in Objective-C with, on actions, a direct change of the underlying _currentPage without using the setter, preventing KVO from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may detect the taps with [`sendAction(_:to:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction) and read the value of currentPage at that moment.

```
class MyPageControl: UIPageControl {
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        updateSomething(for: currentPage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you asked and answered the question at the same time (I mean literal same time) !

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi Simultaneous Q&A is a Stack Overflow feature explained here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 2):

From Apple Doc : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol)

When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, the control sends the valueChanged event for handling by the delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the currentPage property to determine the page to display. The page control advances only one page in either direction. The currently viewed page is indicated by a white dot. Depending on the device, a certain number of dots are displayed on the screen before they are clipped.

Code:

```
pageControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(pageControlTapHandler(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

//or

pageControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(pageControlTapHandler(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)



...

func pageControlTapHandler(sender:UIPageControl) {
    print("currentPage:", sender.currentPage) //currentPage: 1
}
```

Comment: We're in the subclass of the pageControl itself, so it should be `self.addTarget(self, ...`.